# Splitting by string only works on first sub-string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem:**

My current code only splits on the first matching sub-string it finds. I want it to split and add a span tag to every matching sub-string. Here is my code:

```js
$('#orderhighlight').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).html());
                var textclean = $(this).html().replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, ' <br /> ');      
                $(this).html(textclean);
                console.log($(this).html());

                var text = $(this).html().replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');        
                $(this).html(text);
});

$('#rechighlight').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).html());
                var texttwo = $(this).html().replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, ' <br /> ');      
                $(this).html(texttwo);
}); 


var one = $('#orderhighlight').html().split(' ');    
var two = $('#rechighlight').html().split(' ');
one.forEach(function(w, i){
        var ind2 = two.indexOf(w);
        
        if(two.includes(one[i])){
             one[i] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";
             two[ind2] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";

             }  
})


$('#orderhighlight').html(one.join(' '));
$('#rechighlight').html(two.join(' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Ordered </p>
<p id="orderhighlight">006 <br> 007 <br> 008 <br> 009</p>
<br>
<p> Received </p>
<p id="rechighlight">006 <br> 006 <br> 008</p>
```

Run the code and look at the output. You will notice that the 2nd instance of '006' under received is being skipped over.

**Attempted Solutions:**

I have tried to change my `if` to a `while` statement but I soon realized I would have to make several more changes. So I swapped my `split(' ')` to `split('<br>')` but then it just removes my `<br>` tags and skips adding any spans. I also worked around with checking the individual strings and it just seems to end the string after I split it. So what exactly is stopping it from adding the span to each sub-string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that only one item of the `two` array can be modified for each item in `one`. So, since there's only one `006` in `one`, only one `006` can be replaced in `two`. You were almost there with your idea of a `while` loop; it actually doesn't require that much restructuring. See the code below (For consistency, I have also replaced calls to `include` with a check that the `indexOf` is greater than or equal to 0, since a value of -1 means that it was not found).

```js
$('#orderhighlight').each(function() {
                var textclean = $(this).html().replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, ' <br /> ');      
                $(this).html(textclean);

                var text = $(this).html().replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');        
                $(this).html(text);
});

$('#rechighlight').each(function() {
                var texttwo = $(this).html().replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, ' <br /> ');      
                $(this).html(texttwo);
}); 


var one = $('#orderhighlight').html().split(' ');    
var two = $('#rechighlight').html().split(' ');

one.forEach(function(w, i){
        var ind2 = two.indexOf(w);
        
        if(ind2 >= 0){
             one[i] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";
             while (ind2 >= 0) {
                  two[ind2] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";
                  ind2 = two.indexOf(w);
             }
        }  
})


$('#orderhighlight').html(one.join(' '));
$('#rechighlight').html(two.join(' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Ordered </p>
<p id="orderhighlight">006 <br> 007 <br> 008 <br> 009</p>
<br>
<p> Received </p>
<p id="rechighlight">006 <br> 006 <br> 008</p>
```

Drew's answer works for this specific situation since there's only two `006`'s in the array, but this method will work for any number of those values.

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly right for multiple occurrences! I had not realized that issue about `two.includes(one[i])` as I thought it would check for each, but now looking at it I see that my logic was way off.

Answer (score 0):

The function indexOf always grabs the index of the *first* occurrence of the specified value in the string, which is why your while loop solution didn't work (because it kept grabbing the first occurrence each time. If you are only going to have 2 occurrences of the string, you could use lastIndexOf, which as you might have guessed - returns the last index of the string. Here's a solution with that:

```
$('#orderhighlight').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).html());
                var textclean = $(this).html().replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, ' <br /> ');           
                $(this).html(textclean);
                console.log($(this).html());

                var text = $(this).html().replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');        
                $(this).html(text);
});

$('#rechighlight').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).html());
                var texttwo = $(this).html().replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, ' <br /> ');         
                $(this).html(texttwo);
}); 


var one = $('#orderhighlight').html().split(' ');               
var two = $('#rechighlight').html().split(' ');
one.forEach(function(w, i){
        var ind2 = two.indexOf(w);
        var ind3 = two.lastIndexOf(w);

        if(two.includes(one[i])){
             one[i] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";
             two[ind2] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";

             }
        if(two.includes(one[i])){
             one[i] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";
             two[ind3] = "<span style='color:orange'>" + w + "</span>";

             }  
});


$('#orderhighlight').html(one.join(' '));
$('#rechighlight').html(two.join(' '));

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Ordered </p>
<p id="orderhighlight">006 <br> 007 <br> 008 <br> 009</p>
<br>
<p> Received </p>
<p id="rechighlight">006 <br> 006 <br> 008</p>
```

You can see I simply added in an extra step to highlight the last occurrence as well. This works if you're going to have at most 2 occurrences. If you plan to have more possible occurrences, then I suggest you take the substring of w starting from the point where the first occurrence is to the end of the string, then doing the same evaluation again to see if it still contains the substring.